# Exclude useragents so Google crawls my site

Tags: java, cookies, google-crawlers

I have a script on my site (age check cookie script)

```
<script>
        if(!$.cookie("date") && [*id*] != 1) {
        window.location="/[~1~]";
    }                                                        
</script>
```

Since 10 januari Google removed the pages with the script from the Google index (site:mysite.com)

I need to exclude crawlers from the script.
But how can I do this?

//////

As you could see here pages are not in the index anymore:
[image]

Seems Google was able to detect the JS?
Some more info about this date: 
https://www.besthostnews.com/google-update-massive-serp-volatility-continues/

Comment: This site is for programming questions. SEO is off-topic.

Comment: Well its about my site being visible to the public.

Comment: Out of interest, what is that script meant to do?

Comment: When the cookie isn't there you get redirected to the age check page. When adding your age, you get a cookie and able to see all pages of the website. With javascript disabled the page can be visited thow without redirect.

Comment: I think I have found my answer. When it works I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Slowly Google is adding pages with age check!
Hopefully usefull for someone else.

```
<script>

var botPattern = "(googlebot\/|Googlebot-Mobile|Googlebot-Image|Google favicon|Mediapartners-Google|bingbot|slurp|java|wget|curl|Commons-HttpClient|Python-urllib|libwww|httpunit|nutch|phpcrawl|msnbot|jyxobot|FAST-WebCrawler|FAST Enterprise Crawler|biglotron|teoma|convera|seekbot|gigablast|exabot|ngbot|ia_archiver|GingerCrawler|webmon |httrack|webcrawler|grub.org|UsineNouvelleCrawler|antibot|netresearchserver|speedy|fluffy|bibnum.bnf|findlink|msrbot|panscient|yacybot|AISearchBot|IOI|ips-agent|tagoobot|MJ12bot|dotbot|woriobot|yanga|buzzbot|mlbot|yandexbot|purebot|Linguee Bot|Voyager|CyberPatrol|voilabot|baiduspider|citeseerxbot|spbot|twengabot|postrank|turnitinbot|scribdbot|page2rss|sitebot|linkdex|Adidxbot|blekkobot|ezooms|dotbot|Mail.RU_Bot|discobot|heritrix|findthatfile|europarchive.org|NerdByNature.B
ot|sistrix crawler|ahrefsbot|Aboundex|domaincrawler|wbsearchbot|summify|ccbot|edisterbot|seznambot|ec2linkfinder|gslfbot|aihitbot|intelium_bot|facebookexternalhit|yeti|RetrevoPageAnalyzer|lb-spider|sogou|lssbot|careerbot|wotbox|wocbot|ichiro|DuckDuckBot|lssrocketcrawler|drupact|webcompanycrawler|acoonbot|openindexspider|gnam gnam spider|web-archive-net.com.bot|backlinkcrawler|coccoc|integromedb|content crawler spider|toplistbot|seokicks-robot|it2media-domain-crawler|ip-web-crawler.com|siteexplorer.info|elisabot|proximic|changedetection|blexbot|arabot|WeSEE:Search|niki-bot|CrystalSemanticsBot|rogerbot|360Spider|psbot|InterfaxScanBot|Lipperhey SEO Service|CC Metadata Scaper|g00g1e.net|GrapeshotCrawler|urlappendbot|brainobot|fr-crawler|binlar|SimpleCrawler|Livelapbot|Twitterbot|cXensebot|smtbot|bnf.fr_bot|A6-Indexer|ADmantX|Facebot|Twitterbot|OrangeBot|memorybot|AdvBot|MegaIndex|SemanticScholarBot|ltx71|nerdybot|xovibot|BUbiNG|Qwantify|archive.org_bot|Applebot|TweetmemeBot|crawler4j|fin
dxbot|SemrushBot|yoozBot|lipperhey|y!j-asr|Domain Re-Animator Bot|AddThis)";
var re = new RegExp(botPattern, 'i');

if(!$.cookie("date") && [*id*] != 1 && !re.test(navigator.userAgent)) {     
    window.location="/[~1~]";
}

</script>
```